# R, best data structure to create a lookup table that creates a possible one to many mapping

Tags: r

Let's say I have a certain product codes that help bucket items (this is a contrived example but will help me get at my goal). Just as an example (sorry this was the best I could do after a few minutes of trying to figure out how to create a table)

```
+--------+---------+
| Fruit  |  Code   |
+--------+---------+
| Apple  | 1,2,3,4 |
| Orange |     6,7 |
| Banana |      10 |
+--------+---------+
```

I would like to create a lookup of sorts so that if I type in "10" it returns "banana", if I type in 6 (or 7 for that matter) it returns "Orange" etc. What datastructure would be best to do this?

Now here's what I've got so far. I'm using a list as my structure.

```
fruitlist = list('Apple' = c(1,2,3,4),
                 'Orange' = c(6,7),
                 'Banana' = c(10)

                 )
```

Then what I tried doing along with the error

```
> which(fruitlist==10)
Error in which(fruitlist == 10) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Then I tried doing

```
> which( 10 %in% fruitlist)
[1] 1
```

The second one at least doesn't error out, but it also gives me 1, which I have no idea what to do with. Can anyone help me out here, what structure should I use.

I really don't want to use a cascading if else loop because the actual data is quite long and more complicated and I don't want to type out a million (if else etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack the list into a dataframe  and search for your value using `match` -

```
lookup_df <- stack(fruitlist)
# gives
  values    ind
1      1  Apple
2      2  Apple
3      3  Apple
4      4  Apple
5      6 Orange
6      7 Orange
7     10 Banana

with(lookup_df, ind[match(10, values)]) # use ind[values == 10] for multiple matches

[1] Banana
Levels: Apple Orange Banana
```

Another way using `sapply`, although I expect it to be slower than above for long lists -

```
names(which(sapply(fruitlist, function(x) 10 %in% x)))

[1] "Banana"
```

Comment: Another way (instead of with, sapply) is to use tidy dialect `lookup_df %>% filter(values==10) %>% pull(ind)`

Comment: Ignore my other comment, I figured out the answer to my question. I do have a follow up, however. Why does sapply magically return a valid value here? I tried the " %in%" as I noted in my original example but it didn't work, why does using "sapply" here make it work suddenly?

Comment: @inferator if you don't mind me asking could you explain what tidy dialect and %>% thing is? I've seen the %operator% syntax before but I never understood how it works

Comment: A bunch of packages and functions developed by rstudio company programmers. You can install them via the 'tidyverse' package. For more info, just google tidyverse. That %>% thing is a pipe. Pipes have been useful in unix OSs, and so they were introduced into R. The whole 'tidy' thing is just about a philosophy for consistent code.